# How to find similar elements based on condition and add them in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am reading XML file and based on some condition I have to find some elements and if found then add them so that only 1 element will come in the output. I have to find this in XSLT 1.0

Please find the payload and condition.

```
<processVoucherDetail>
  <glDistribution>
    <amountDomestic>555.50</amountDomestic>
    <glAccount>
      <businessUnit>123</businessUnit>
      <objectAccount>999</objectAccount>
    </glAccount>
  </glDistribution>
  <glDistribution>
    <amountDomestic>555.50</amountDomestic>
    <glAccount>
      <businessUnit>1234</businessUnit>
      <objectAccount>9998</objectAccount>
    </glAccount>
  </glDistribution>
  <glDistribution>
    <amountDomestic>555.50</amountDomestic>
    <glAccount>
      <businessUnit>123</businessUnit>
      <objectAccount>999</objectAccount>
    </glAccount>
  </glDistribution>
  <voucher>
    <amountGrossDomestic>138.88</amountGrossDomestic>
    <amountTaxDomestic>27.78</amountTaxDomestic>
    <amountTaxableDomestic>111.10</amountTaxableDomestic>
    <payee>
      <entityId>4444</entityId>
    </payee>
    <taxExplanationCode>test</taxExplanationCode>
    <taxRateAreaCode>test</taxRateAreaCode>
  </voucher>
  <voucher>
    <amountGrossDomestic>138.88</amountGrossDomestic>
    <amountTaxDomestic>27.78</amountTaxDomestic>
    <amountTaxableDomestic>111.10</amountTaxableDomestic>

    <payee>
      <entityId>5555</entityId>
    </payee>
    <taxExplanationCode>hello</taxExplanationCode>
    <taxRateAreaCode>hello</taxRateAreaCode>
  </voucher>
  <voucher>
    <amountGrossDomestic>138.88</amountGrossDomestic>
    <amountTaxDomestic>27.78</amountTaxDomestic>
    <amountTaxableDomestic>111.10</amountTaxableDomestic>
    <payee>
      <entityId>6666</entityId>
    </payee>
    <taxExplanationCode>test</taxExplanationCode>
    <taxRateAreaCode>test</taxRateAreaCode>
  </voucher>
</processVoucherDetail>
```

Now in this payload, i have to compare values of businessUnit and objectAccount of glaccount with other businessUnit and objectAccount of glaccount and if found (in above payload 1 glaccount is matching with 3rd glaccount) then I have to find voucher elements whose amountTaxableDomestic values matching with amountDomestic of glaccount and i found more than 1 voucher elements then I need to compare values of taxExplanationCode and taxRateAreaCode within number of vouchers i got above. If I find any 2 or more vouchers with same values of taxExplanationCode and taxRateAreaCode  of another voucher(1st voucher is matching with 3rd voucher) and amountTaxableDomestic  value with amountDomestic of glaccount then I have to add amountDomestic value of all glaccount i got based on above condition and also add values of amountTaxDomestic of all vouhcers i have got based on above condition.

My criteria is quite complex. Please let me know in case anyone wants more explanation.

i am new to XSLT so sample code will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best accomplished using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). I suggest you read the article, study some of the hundreds of examples of the method here on SO, then come back if you have a **specific** question.

Comment: Hello Craig, thank you for ur ans and I read ur artcile and checked some ex as well but it will take me some time to understand this.. :-) if possible , could you please give me the logic which i wanted or some hint as this is quite urgent !! I hope u dont mind :-p , thanks in advance.